# How to connect Gigolo to Nextcloud webdav and open user specific folders

Tags: nextcloud, webdav, gigolo

Gigolo is a very useful package to connect to sFTP, Webdav and other shares. It allows you to access files on those shares in system explorer.

When you add Webdav share from Nextcloud it goes to root folder that contains:

```
addressbooks  files         provisioning      systemtags-relations
avatars       photos        public-calendars  trashbin
calendars     photospublic  system-calendars  uploads
comments      principals    systemtags        versions
```

When I try to navigate into files I get the following error:

> Failed to open directory "files".
>
> HTTP Error: Method Not Allowed.

[image: Gigolo error message http error method Not Allowed]

Path in file explorer (Thunar):

```
dav://USER_NAME@192.168.1.220:8081/remote.php/dav/
```

However I can access files on this path:

```
dav://USER_NAME@192.168.1.220:8081/remote.php/dav/files/USER_NAME/
```

How do I make it open the user folder which I see when I login to Nextcloud directly after I click the share icon in Gigolo?

Gigolo version: 0.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can open the correct path to your user files by setting the connection like this:

[image]

### Entries

- Server holds the server domain or IP
- USER_NAME should be replaced by your Nextcloud user account in both User name and Folder fields.
- Port is based on your Nextcloud setup
- Path is `remote.php/dav`, Nextcloud webdav operate on that URL
- Folder is where you put path to your user files